# Scraping Facebook pages with Goutte

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, web-scraping, goutte

I'm attempting to scrape facebook pages with Goutte in order to gather the 'created date' of a page. 
This is not accessible via the Graph API.

In testing, I am able to retrieve all links from pages like tutsplus and symfony-project however when I attempt to access a page like 'https://www.facebook.com/151116474914629' it returns '2' links which is incorrect.

Code:

```
use Symfony\Component\DomCrawler\Crawler;
use Goutte\Client as Goutte;

public function goutte()
{
    $url_to_traverse = 'https://www.facebook.com/151116474914629';

    $client = new Goutte();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', $url_to_traverse);
    $status_code = $client->getResponse()->getStatus();
    if($status_code==200){
        $a_count = $crawler->filter('a')->count();     
    }
    return $a_count;
}
```

Any ideas on retrieving the full pages contents?

Answer (score 1):

With Facebook, the vast majority of the content of the page is generated dynamically - multiple Ajax calls and so on.  This makes it very, very difficult to scrape.  And of course for any page that's generated dynamically, the "created date" is really the date you request the page, every time.

In the context of web pages, I don't know of an obvious way to obtain a creation date, but the modification date is included as an optional part of the HTTP 1.1 specification.  So, many (but not all) websites will send the Last-Modified header along with the web page.  This header can be modified programmatically and is fairly meaningless on dynamic web pages, so I wouldn't rely on it.

You're out of luck with Facebook in any case.  There's no Last-Modified header (I've checked, including following this particular page's redirect).  And I'm not sure what else you could look for connected to this page, to find the creation date.

In relation to other Goutte operations on this page, and bearing in mind what I've said about dynamic page creation, you can still retrieve *some* content.  Just watch out for redirections.  Using cURL at the command line, you can see that the web page redirects from https://www.facebook.com/151116474914629 to https://www.facebook.com/PhilzCoffeeCastro:

```
me@here:~$ curl --head https://www.facebook.com/151116474914629
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.facebook.com/PhilzCoffeeCastro
[snip]
Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 12:54:01 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Note "Moved Permananently".

So you need to test for the redirection and make sure you're scraping the correct page.

In summary:

- Don't use Goutte to find the last modified time.  You need to parse HTTP headers, so cURL is a better choice.
- Dynamic pages have no meaningful "created date" and are very difficult to scrape anyway
- Always check for page redirects

If you want to find the date when a page first appeared on the Internet, I would suggest trying a different strategy completely: http://www.labnol.org/internet/search/find-publishing-date-of-web-pages/8410/

Disclaimer: I do not know what "the Graph API" is, so I admit I may not fully understand the context of your question.  I hope some of the above is helpful though.